# How to access redux in a new react class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

In App I have a button that saves a message and another that creates a new component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { AppState } from "./redux/store";
import { ChatState } from "./redux/chat/types";
import { sendMessage } from "./redux/chat/actions";
import Test from './components/test'

interface AppProps { sendMessage: typeof sendMessage; chat: ChatState }

const App: React.FC<AppProps>  = (props: AppProps) => {
  const { sendMessage } = props;  
  const AddChat = () => {
    sendMessage({ user: "John", message: "Message one", timestamp: new Date().getTime() });
  };
  const AddNode = () => {
    const newNode = new Test();
//                     ^ Error
  };

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={AddChat}>Add Chat</button>
      <button onClick={AddNode}>Add Node</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}


const addState = (state: AppState) => ({ chat: state.chat });
const ReduxConnect = connect(addState, { sendMessage }) (App)

export { ReduxConnect as App} ;
```

The error here is

```
(alias) const Test: ConnectedComponent<typeof Test, Pick<{}, never>>
import Test
----------------
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(324, 10): An argument for 'props' was not provided.
```

So what is it expecting? How can I find out? The constructor doesn't have props, does it want me to declare some, pass some into the new component or what? I'm just not that familiar with class-based components when it comes to redux

The Test component looks like

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { AppState } from "../redux/store";
import { ChatState } from "../redux/chat/types";
import { sendMessage } from "../redux/chat/actions";

class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  sendMessage
}

  export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

I want to be able to sendMessage and get state from this new component

**UPDATE**
Changing the class component to this fixes the previous but gives a new error

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { AppState } from "../redux/store";
import { ChatState } from "../redux/chat/types";
import { sendMessage } from "../redux/chat/actions";

interface AppProps { sendMessage: typeof sendMessage; chat: ChatState }

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}

const addState = (state: AppState) => ({ chat: state.chat });
const ReduxConnect = connect(addState, { sendMessage }) (Test)
//                                                        ^ Error
export { ReduxConnect as Test} ;
```

and the error is

```
Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
    Type 'Test' is not assignable to type 'Component<never, any, any>'.
      Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
        Type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

When I hover over `new Test` I get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting your `Test` component to Redux -- which wants to pass in props -- yet you're not accepting any constructor params, so they're not getting passed in. If you just omit your `constructor` override I think this will work.

**EDIT:**

```
class Test extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

I think this default prop param will now mean you don't have to send in a `{}` when instantiating `Test`.

Comment: Same error, unfortunately, is there a way to allow the needed constructor params?

Comment: can you show me your changed code? Also, don't redefine the constructor, just get rid of it in `Test`.

Comment: Okay I think I know why. The connected component is still expecting you to pass in SOME props, so that it can "merge" them with the redux props, try passing in an empty object: `new Test({})`.

Comment: Getting closer! The error I get now is `'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)

Comment: Wait, sorry my bad, I think you do need the constructor, one sec editing my answer to show what it should probably look like.

Comment: If I add the constructor back I get https://i.imgur.com/7UEvmZz.png and the same error if I remove the empty object {}

Comment: Try it now with my EDIT.

Comment: Playing whack-a-mole here, alright try just sending in the empty object I guess.